# How to filter an array of objects into different segments in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

Good Evening,

**The Problem**

I use a GET request to receive an array of Notes from an API. Each note has a type (ATC, Imaging, and Lab)

The problem is that the endpoint gets me a list of all the notes together, but I want to separate them into a `UISegmentedControl` by the type of note. i.e Segment 1 would have ATC, Segment 2 would have Imaging, and the final segment will be Lab.

**The Code**

The Note Model

```
var id: Int
var name: String?
var date: Date
var createdByFirstName: String?
var createdByLastName: String?
var type: String?
var isClosed: Bool
```

The API Request

```
func getAssociatedInjuryNotes(with injuryId: Int, completion: @escaping ((Result<[AssociatedInjuryNote], InjuryError>) -> Void)) {
        let baseURL = self.configuration.baseURL
        let endPoint = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("injury/\(injuryId)/notes")
        API.shared.httpClient.get(endPoint) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                do {
                    let injuryAssociatedNote = try API.jsonDecoder.decode([AssociatedInjuryNote].self, from: response.data)
                    completion(.success(injuryAssociatedNote))
                } catch (let error) {
                    completion(.failure(.unknown(message: error.localizedDescription)))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(.unknown(message: error.localizedDescription)))
            }
        }
    }
```

How I get the data in the view controller

```
fileprivate class InjuryAssociatedNotesViewModel {
    private(set) var injuryId: Int
    @Published private(set) var injuryNotes: [AssociatedInjuryNote] = []
    @Published private(set) var error: String?

    init(injuryId: Int) {
        self.injuryId = injuryId
    }

    func refresh() {
        InjuryAPI.shared.getAssociatedInjuryNotes(with: injuryId) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let associatedNotes):
                self.injuryNotes = associatedNotes.sorted(by: {
                    $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending
                })
            case .failure(let error):
                self.error = error.localizedDescription
            }
        }
    }

}
```

CollectionView Setup

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let viewModel = self.viewModel else { return UICollectionViewCell() }

        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NoteCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? NoteCell else { fatalError("Could not dequeue cell of type: '\(NoteCell.self)'") }


        let injuryAssociatedNote = viewModel.injuryNotes[indexPath.item]
        cell.configure(with: injuryAssociatedNote)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let viewModel = self.viewModel else { return 0 }
        return viewModel.injuryNotes.count
    }
```

If anyone can point me in the correct direction it would be greatly appreciated, I am struggingling with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

First, given that there a finite number of note types, I would model them as an enum instead of a String:

```
enum NoteType {
    case atc
    case imaging
    case lab
}
```

You could always add an `.unknown` case in the event that your backend provides a String that your client doesn't recognize. It may also be beneficial to give your `NoteType` enum a raw type of String and have each rawValue correspond to the values your backend will provide.

Second, it's a bit unclear exactly what you want to accomplish with a `UISegmentedControl`. My assumption is that you want a separate segment for each different type of Note? If that's the case, you could make the above enum conform to `CaseIterable` and create a segment for each value found in `NoteType`'s `allCases` array. (If you're going the route of having `NoteType`s be Strings, then each segment's title could be set to every case's rawValue). It really all depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Third, I *think* in the end what you're wanting is three (or however many `NoteType`s exist) separate arrays of Notes where each `Note` is of the same type. That way you can determine what your `UICollectionView`'s datasource is depending on which segment of the `UISegmentedControl` is selected. If that's what you're wanting (feel free to correct me), you can accomplish that via a simple filter call:

```
let sortedNotes = associatedNotes.sorted(by: {
    $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending
})
let atcNotes = sortedNotes.filter { $0.type == .atc }
let imagingNotes = sortedNotes.filter { $0.type == .imaging }
let labNotes = sortedNotes.filter { $0.type == .lab }
```

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for the prompt and informative response. It is helping me :). You are fully understanding what I am trying to do, I want to separate each note type into a segment. So I created the NoteType enum with raw values, I added the code to sort the notes to the API Call. Now I am lost about where to use the sorted values (atcNotes, imagingNotes, labNotes). Would I write some logic in cellForItemAt, and would I need to create an @Published var for each note as I do with injuryNotes in the API Call

Comment: Its difficult to fully answer your questions without knowing the extent of both your UI setup and the logic of all the classes at play here, but I'll answer as best I can: "would I need to create an @Published var for each note as I do with injuryNotes in the API Call" Yes, you'll likely want three class-level arrays just like you have `injuryNotes`

Comment: "Now I am lost about where to use the sorted values" -- this is impossible to answer without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish. My guess would be that you'd want to display all of the Notes in a list? If so, you'll want a separate UI component (UICollectionView or UITableView). The UISegmentedControl will be used to toggle which types of Notes are displayed by the collection

Comment: "Would I write some logic in cellForItemAt" -- this also is impossible to answer without knowing how your code is structured. Will the UISegmentedControl and the UICollectionView live inside the UICollectionViewCell that you're calling `configure` on? If so, maybe they're passed into the `configure` method and your collection's dataSource is set in there. Again, this is total guesswork without knowing what you're going for